# Convert dataframe into dictionary based on list value which match with column value in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have requirement to plot graphs with below dataset in different colors and linestyle based on selection of columns so i need to help to create dictionary to achieve or any other suggestions please suggest:

```
DCID    Date    AvgPclick           PE                  RIG                 PRAUC               AUC                 CTR
108 2021-09-21  0.708933545301133   -0.0315905101767838 0.183956575870034   -0.474283991404417  0.903244678090041   0.788005171920178
108 2021-09-24  0.707041434153454   -0.0367966166237633 0.185246255961045   -0.471894596368345  0.90490401038347    0.789823880579267
2   2021-09-21  0.828546584214457   0.0322740317687793  0.186304490387533   -0.404177063630338  0.934970292892616   0.798609945295051
2   2021-09-24  0.827485566796294   0.0306502876279096  0.185816688322522   -0.404150730102847  0.9348035339994     0.798204584657664
4   2021-10-05  0.744979850617935   0.0209816216587382  0.21781206703246    -0.45647439940301   0.910211203227132   0.807481208430387
4   2021-10-09  0.750983088193199   0.0079984577012481  0.223085020955023   -0.441082642736994  0.917790063534653   0.810912424306168
```

I want to convet above dataframe into dictonary as below so please help me how to achieve this:

```
[
   {
      "108":[{
         "AvgPclick":0.710877444778147,
         "PE":0.0972292165515269,
         "RIG":0.125791580059127,
         "PRAUC":0.841291977556287,
         "AUC":0.752902365122059,
         "CTR":0.647884174113006
      },{
         "AvgPclick":0.710877444778147,
         "PE":0.0972292165515269,
         "RIG":0.125791580059127,
         "PRAUC":0.841291977556287,
         "AUC":0.752902365122059,
         "CTR":0.647884174113006
      }]
      "2":[{
         "AvgPclick":0.710877444778147,
         "PE":0.0972292165515269,
         "RIG":0.125791580059127,
         "PRAUC":0.841291977556287,
         "AUC":0.752902365122059,
         "CTR":0.647884174113006
      },{
         "AvgPclick":0.710877444778147,
         "PE":0.0972292165515269,
         "RIG":0.125791580059127,
         "PRAUC":0.841291977556287,
         "AUC":0.752902365122059,
         "CTR":0.647884174113006
      }],
      "4":[{
         "AvgPclick":0.710877444778147,
         "PE":0.0972292165515269,
         "RIG":0.125791580059127,
         "PRAUC":0.841291977556287,
         "AUC":0.752902365122059,
         "CTR":0.647884174113006
      },{
         "AvgPclick":0.710877444778147,
         "PE":0.0972292165515269,
         "RIG":0.125791580059127,
         "PRAUC":0.841291977556287,
         "AUC":0.752902365122059,
         "CTR":0.647884174113006
      }]
   }
]
```

Comment: What is your objective? To plot or to make the dictionary? I think you can achieve your dict with `df.to_dict('index')`. But libs like seaborn are already made to plot dataframes in advanced ways, I assume what you want to do is possible with just the dataframe. Converting to a dict feels anti pattern

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Based on sample data Help in Ploting Metrix Graph. i.e. I want to plot 4 different graphs based list that are 1.Metrics_Vaules = ['AUC', 'PE', 'RIG', 'AvgPclick,CTR'] 2.LNStyle_Val = ['-', '-', '-', '-,--'] -- These are the different line style respectively for Metrics_Vaules list 3.dcid_list = ['64', '8', '89', '4', '108', '2'] 4.dcid_names = ['AU_TA_PGC', 'UK_TA_PGC', 'DE_TA_PGC', 'FR_TA_PGC', 'N10_TA_PGC', 'US_TA_PGC'] -- shows name in charts based on dcid_list i.e. for 8 - "UK_TA_PGC" 5. Clr_Vaules = ['b', 'r', 'k', 'g', 'y', 'm'] -- these with respective of dcid_names....